# iPhone iMessages don't arrive after restart and before entering passcode

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

This is the timeline:

1. iPhone runs out of battery and powers off.
2. Connect the charger to the iPhone.
3. iPhone powers on automatically. I'm not paying attention to it so I don't enter the passcode yet.
4. iMessages are not delivered.
5. Enter the passcode.
6. iMessages start arriving.

Is this the expected behaviour?

I would like to be notified if someone sends me a text, without having to explicitly check my iPhone. Can this be done?

Comment: I couldn't say for certain, but this sounds about right. Phone on a fresh startup hasn't yet been signed in… so your Apple ID isn't yet signed in to the necessary services for any sync to happen.